# jquery window.open(url) on ipad

Tags: jquery, ipad

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" />     

$('#btn-fb-share').click(function() {
        $('#btn-fb-share').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        window.open(url,"Mywindow","location=yes,menubar=yes");
    });
```

On my Ipad (Where i made a Shortcut to the Website on the Home-Screen) the link does not open in a new Window (Safari). How can i solve this? On my PC the link opens correctly in a new Window.

EDIT: I'll try to explain it clearer.

What is happening: My Web-App open's the url in the same Window like my app.
[image: Process Flow Is]

What should happen is: The Facebook page opens in a new Tab in safari. (I can demonstrate this if i open my site over safari and not over my web app.)

[image: Process Flow should be]

I hope you can see the difference now. I need to open my Link in Safari in a new Tab. But right now it keeps open it in my Window, where I dont have "return Button".

The only difference between the two pictures is. The first picture is the Website saved on my Homescreen. The second picture is the Website opened directly in Safari.

Comment: http://www.devdaily.com/iphone/iphone-ipad-javascript-windows-dialogs-open-html and http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006482-SW1 < scroll down to _"Use Supported JavaScript Windows and Dialogs"_

Comment: I can't find the solution to my Problem there.. There is nothing about opening a Link in a new Tab/Window.

Comment: Both links talk about using `window.open()` with iOS. I tested this js on an iPad and it worked fine: http://jsfiddle.net/flackend/rb4n8/

Comment: I dont know if you understood my Problem. If I open the Website over Safari it works. But if I open it over the Shortcut (Web-App) on my Homescreen it doesn't work.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What _is_ happening and what do you _want_ to happen?

Comment: I updated my Question. I hope it is clear now. Btw i also tested if it's because of facebook. But the same thing happens when i try to open www.google.com.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did a Google search and found [this thread on macrumors.com](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1059273) with the same question that explains:

*For links that I want to open within the WebApp and not open in Safari, I use this:*

```
<a onclick="parent.location='http://url.com/page.html'">Link</a>
```

*For links that I want to open in Safari, I use the standard HTML link:*

```
<a href="http://url.com/another_page.html">Link</a>
```

So I did another Google search and found how to detect if you're using iOS in JavaScript: http://forrst.com/posts/JavaScript_iOS_Detection-Ofa

Here's my solution:

```
var url = "http://www.google.com/";

// Get the user agent string
var deviceAgent = navigator.userAgent;
// Set var to iOS device name or null
var ios = deviceAgent.toLowerCase().match(/(iphone|ipod|ipad)/);

$('#btn-fb-share').click(function() {

    if (ios) {
        // This is the line that matters
        $(this).attr('href', url);
    } else {
        // Your code that works for desktop browsers
        $('#btn-fb-share').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        window.open(url,2789432749274249,"location=yes,menubar=yes");
    }
});
```

I tested it in Chrome on a desktop, and on iOS from Safari and via a Home Screen WebApp. Here is a link to my working test: http://flackend.com/other/ios-test/

Note that you need to set the link's `target` to `_blank` for it to open in a new tab in Safari on iOS (not from a WebApp instance, if you opened it in the Safari app). You can set that directly in your HTML markup or do it with jQuery using `attr`.

Comment: YOU sir, saved my day! Thanks alot! Take all the Reputation :P