# JavaScript popup window on ipad

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, popupwindow

I have not been able to open popup windows on ipad using the JavaScript window.open function, 
that is why I have been trying to make an alternative solution for ipad's, inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11523379/jquery-window-openurl-on-ipad) thread.

```
 function newPopup(url) {

    // Get the user agent string
    var deviceAgent = navigator.userAgent;
    // Set var to iOS device name or null
    var ios = deviceAgent.toLowerCase().match(/(iphone|ipod|ipad)/);

     if (ios) {
        // This is the line that matters
        $(this).attr('href', url);
    }else{  
           popupWindow = window.open(
            url,'popUpWindow','height=250,width=350,left=50,top=50,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no')
    }
}
```

Still I can't open a new window on ipad. Is there another way to target ipad?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can find here

```
if( navigator.platform === 'iPad' ){
    alert('hurray');
}
```

More details read here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID.platform

Also detects iphone if needed and other platforms.

```
if( navigator.platform === 'iPhone' ){
    alert('hurray');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! It seems like I can use this in order to target iPad.. but what function can I use to open a new window that will work on iPad as well?

Comment: Popup on safari and chrome are default close so you wont have success in that but you can try open new tab or using some modals as for example TB modals. Www.bootstrap.com